# VB 2010: Search for strings within large text blocks (e.g. HTML source)

Tags: html, string, parsing, search, full-text-search

I'm developing an app for WP7 and Win7 that will get info extracted directly from particular websites. The app will download the HTML source and parse through it to find the required string. The string may not have tags. I have tried traditional TextBox.SelectionText method but it takes way too long to be viable.

Is there a faster way to hunt for strings within HTML source?

Answer (score 1):

The "String.IndexOf" method should be the most efficient way to determine if a string is located within the HTML of the page.

Therefore, if you have the HTML files from the various websites you can load the page into a string one by one and use the "IndexOf" to identify whether a certain string exists within the page.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Is it possible to use 'String.IndexOf' to find multiple instances of the search query in the HTML source?